# Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='VersionManager']

Tags: sitecore-client, serialization

On serializing part of the tree in Sitecore I get the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find configuration node: 
databases/database[@id='VersionManager'] at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, 
Boolean assert) at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, 
Boolean assert) at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert) at 
Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name) at 
Sitecore.Data.Serialization.ItemReference.GetItem() at 
Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.CleanupObsoleteShortens() --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean 
constructor) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters,
 Object[] arguments) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, 
Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at 
Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) at 
Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args) at (Object , Object[] ) at 
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

I installed Version Manager from the Market Place a while ago and I've tried uninstalling it. I can't find any further references anywhere but I'm still getting the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try to open /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx page? You should be able to see where database[@id='VersionManager'] is referenced

Comment: @CristiVulturar I've looked in there and can find no references

Comment: Could you also verify if you removed the serialized items that the module created? And if in showconfig there are any references to Version Manager, not only database[@=

Comment: You need to look in Commands.config

Answer (score 1):

The version manager module has this config file:

```
<configuration xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    
    <events timingLevel="custom">
      <event name="item:versionAdded" >
        <handler type="Sitecore.VersionManager.Handlers.VersionAddedHandler" method="OnVersionAdded"/>
      </event>
    </events>

    <pipelines>
      <getContentEditorWarnings>
        <processor type="Sitecore.VersionManager.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.HasEnoughVersion, Sitecore.VersionManager"/>
      </getContentEditorWarnings>
    </pipelines>
    
    <commands>
      <command name="version:clean" type="Sitecore.VersionManager.Commands.Clean, Sitecore.VersionManager" />
      <command name="version:refresh" type="Sitecore.VersionManager.Commands.Refresh, Sitecore.VersionManager" />
      <command name="version:cleanall"  type="Sitecore.VersionManager.Commands.CleanAll, Sitecore.VersionManager"/>
    </commands>
  
    <settings>
      <!--  Enables/disables automatic versions cleanup.
            Defaults to true.
      -->
      <setting name="VersionManager.AutomaticCleanupEnabled" value="false" />
      <!--  Sets the count of the latest versions to keep. 
            Defaults to 5.
      -->      
      <setting name="VersionManager.NumberOfVersionsToKeep" value="4" />
      <!--  Enables/disables a serializing of deleted versions
            Defaults to true.
      -->
      <setting name="VersionManager.ArchiveDeletedVersions" value="true" />
      <!--  Enables/disables a warning in the Content Editor
            when the item already has ItemVersionManager.NumberOfVersionsToKeep (N) versions.
            Defaults to true.
      -->
      <setting name="VersionManager.ShowContentEditorWarnings" value="true" />
      
      <!--  Sets root items in the content tree
            for processing versions checking.
            Defaults to /sitecore/content/Home.
      -->
      <setting name="VersionManager.Roots">
        <root value="/sitecore/content/Home"/>
      </setting>

      <AntiCsrf cookieName="__CSRFCOOKIE" formFieldName="__CSRFTOKEN" detectionResult="RaiseException" errorPage="" enabled="true">
        <rules>
          <rule name="shell">
            <ignore wildcard="/sitecore/shell/*applications/versions/version*manager*\?*Cart_itemsGrid_Callback=yes" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </AntiCsrf>
      
    </settings>
    
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Please check which of these settings, commands , pipelines are still enabled? and please delete the file : **Sitecore.VersionManager.dll**

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and assuming you removed the module's files from *bin, app_config and sitecore_modules* it seems that there are still some errors happening during serialization. I suggest you take a look at what items you have in the serialized folders and also go to sitecore core database and remove the items that the VersionManager has installed:

```
\items\core\sitecore\content\Applications\Versions\Clean Up
\items\core\sitecore\content\Applications\Versions\Version Manager
\items\core\sitecore\content\Documents and settings\All users\Start menu\Programs\Version Manager\
\items\core\sitecore\layout\Layouts\Tools\Version Manager\
```